# How to edit request parameters received by post in SpringBoot in a handler method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In a SpringBoot controller, is there a way to edit request parameters received in post in a handler method and forward them to another handler method?

sample.html

```
<form id="sample" method="post" th:action="@{/methodA}">
     <input type="submit" name="dummykey" value="param_A" class="button" form="sample" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
// Handler Method A
@RequestMapping(value = "/methodA", params = "dummykey=param_A")
  public String methodA(){
  /* edit RequestParameter: dummykey = param_B */
  return "forward:/methodB";
}

// Handler Method B
@RequestMapping(value = "/methodB", params = "dummykey=param_B")
  public String methodB(){
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Why exactly do you try to do? Why don't you put the common code in a separate method?

Comment: Due to certain circumstances, I am required to configure my application with only one URL. Therefore, I want to use only params to determine which handler method to call, and on the other hand, I want to be able to call other handlers from one handler. The `/methodA(B)` is written separately for clarity, but is actually a single URL.

Comment: Sure that's why you should create multiple controller methods but have the logic in a separate method